# no such option --with-allure when running nosetests allure plugin

Tags: python, nose, allure

I am trying to get the nose allure plugin to work with nosetests for a simple test. I can get it working on my local machine but after having installed all the necessary python packages on my remote server and running there I get the following error

> [root@server kieran]# nosetests test.py --nologcapture --with-allure --logdir=./allure-xmls
>
> Usage: nosetests [options]
>
> nosetests: error: no such option: --with-allure

I checked the necessary packages both locally and remotely and they are the same, what am I missing here?

Local list of packages

```
astroid (1.3.6)
autopep8 (1.1.1)
click (3.3)
coverage (4.0b3)
docopt (0.6.2)
dv (0.0.0)
ecdsa (0.13)
EnmUtils (0.0.0)
EnmUtilsInt (0.0.0)
enum34 (1.0.4)
epydoc (3.0.1)
Fabric (1.10.1)
fakeredis (0.6.1)
linecache2 (1.0.0)
logilab-common (0.63.2)
lxml (3.4.4)
mock (1.0.1)
MySQL-python (1.2.5)
namedlist (1.7)
nose (1.3.7)
nose-allure-plugin (1.0.1)
nose-cprof (0.1-0)
parameterizedtestcase (0.1.0)
paramiko (1.15.2)
pep8 (1.6.2)
pip (7.1.0)
py (1.4.30)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pylint (1.4.3)
pytest (2.7.2)
pytest-allure-adaptor (1.6.6)
redis (2.10.3)
requests (2.7.0)
selenium (2.45.0)
setuptools (18.0.1)
six (1.9.0)
traceback2 (1.4.0)
Unipath (1.0)
unittest2 (1.0.1)
wheel (0.24.0)
(env)
```

List on server

```
[root@server kieran]# pip list

argparse (1.2.1)
coverage (3.0.1)
distribute (0.6.10)
enum34 (1.0)
ethtool (0.6)
firstboot (1.110)
glusterfs-api (3.6.0.29)
iniparse (0.3.1)
iwlib (1.0)
lxml (3.5.0)
M2Crypto (0.20.2)
MySQL-python (1.2.3rc1)
namedlist (1.7)
nose (1.3.7)
nose-allure-plugin (1.0.1)
ordereddict (1.2)
oz (0.12.0)
pip (7.1.0)
py (1.4.30)
pycurl (7.19.0)
pygpgme (0.1)
pytest (2.7.2)
pytest-allure-adaptor (1.6.6)
python-meh (0.11)
scdate (1.9.60)
setuptools (0.6rc11)
six (1.9.0)
slip (0.2.20)
Unipath (0.2.1)
unittest2 (0.5.1)
urlgrabber (3.9.1)
yum-metadata-parser (1.1.2)
```

Comment: Where the `nosetests` is pointing to: `which nosetests`?

Comment: Hi @alecxe thanks for the fast response! 

[root@server kieran]# which nosetests
/usr/bin/nosetests

Comment: I just realized i had my virtualenv activated locally, i have since deactivated and I now get the same error as I do on the server. Stupid but i'm glad they are both consistent at least. I must have something in that virtualenv that i have left out

Answer (score 2):

@Kieran, you just needed to install the plugin in the virtual environment you are running the tests.
Try this:
pip install nose-allure-plugin